# Neovim: how to send keys to terminal emulator

Tags: command-line, terminal, neovim

When I open up a nvim terminal emulator and enter the following command, trying to execute command 'python':

```
:normal! ipython
```

It turned out the register content is pasted onto the screen, as if 'p' is pressed under normal mode, even if 'i' has been pressed in prior to (supposedly) enter terminal-insert mode.

This does not help either:

```
:execute "normal! ipython\<CR>"
```

Where have I gone wrong, and how could I do it correctly?

Comment: I don't use Neovim but, f I'm not mistaken, opening the terminal already puts you into "terminal-insert" mode (the feature would be even more pointless otherwise). You should look into why it doesn't instead of looking for a workaround.

Comment: @romainl That's where vim and neovim come to difference, and why I emphasised that I'm using neovim. When you open up a terminal emulator, vim puts you in insert mode while neovim puts you in terminal-normal mode, where you need to manually input a command or press a key (i or a) to enter input mode.

Comment: I guess it would be an alternative solution to use the good ol' vim terminal in neovim... but I dunno know how to set that.

Comment: People should really stop tagging their questions with both `vim` and `neovim` tags, it's a waste of time for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`feedkeys()`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/builtin.html#feedkeys()) solves the issue. So executing the following command in terminal buffer in normal mode produce "python" on the prompt as if typed by the user:

```
:call feedkeys('ipython')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:normal! ipython
```

doesn't mean "run the program". It means "switch to Normal mode and run `!`" which is [a filter command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#!); then run `i` that is switch to Insert mode and insert "python".

To run a command from the vim command line use

```
:!ipython
```

Comment: Thanks answering, but I think you misunderstood my idea: I'm trying to execute the 'python' command inside nvim's *terminal emulator* (so that I can start python repl without leaving nvim, while `:!python` exits the programme automatically and is not what I'm looking for); what you have said, "...then run i that is switch to Insert mode and insert "python"", is exactly I'm intending to do.

Comment: @Futarimiti I don't believe you can use Insert mode in a terminal window. Perhaps [`term_sendkeys()`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_sendkeys%28%29) could help.

Comment: `term_sendkeys()` is vim’s terminal API and sadly does not work in neovim.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against `feedkeys()` as it requires you to consider switching modes, avoiding mapping and escaping. Plus it cannot be used on non-current window due to its buffered nature (`win_gotoid(term_window); feedkeys("als\<CR>"); win_gotoid(current_window)` will insert "ls" in current window, not one with terminal).

Better solution is to use `chansend(window_channel, "ls\n" )`, you can find the channel number from `b:terminal_job_id`.